# Choosing the size of the image - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this code to create a image from prtscreen :

```
$Bitmap = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap (2200,2200)
$Size = New-object System.Drawing.Size 2400,1800
$FromImage = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($Bitmap)
$FromImage.copyfromscreen(0,0,0,0, $Size, ([System.Drawing.CopyPixelOperation]::SourceCopy))
$Bitmap.Save("c:\temp\screenshot.jpg",([system.drawing.imaging.imageformat]::bmp))
```

My problem is that I need to create large size images. I could do it using imageformat BMP ,but now I need to choose the size of the image in MB . I need to choose from 1 to 50 MB.

Can you help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the BMP format, the size of the created file is going to be based on the width/height of the bitmap.  I also notice you're saving this image as a JPEG.  In that case, you should probably save using `[Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg`.

Try a different PixelFormat e.g.:

```
$Bitmap = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap (2200,2200,'Format24bppRgb')
```

Comment: Hi Keith, I did this ntentionally. The extension must be JPG, but if I use the size is too small. So I'm using the BMP format and saving as JPG. My big problem is to choose the size. Need to be large between 1 and 50 MB

Comment: If I create a 2200x2200 bmp 24-bit color, the file size is ~14MB.  Try a different PixelFormat enum value to see if you can get a higher color depth.

Comment: Hi Keith, unfortunately does not works too (changing the Pixel Format). The max that I can get is 18MB :(  Anyway, thanks for trying :)